# Acceptance of my questions

Tags: support, accepted-answer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

What does "acceptance" mean and how do I accept the answers I get?

There are many that I want to accept, but I don't know how.

Comment: Accept the one you feel solved your problem or was close to solving your problem or othe one that you think will solve others problem. BTW this must be discussed at meta.stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 2):

On questions that you create, there's a check mark next to every answer. Click on the checkbox next to the answer you like: this will mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: Hi, I checked the tick box next to answers. But still it says 0% acceptance, 15 reputations.
How does acceptance score increase?